# WebLogic Server always taking a quick dip in service threads

Tags: multithreading, weblogic

we have a HP BAC probe attached on one of our WebLogic servers and we have noticed that the server is often always taking a sudden and deep "dip" in the number of service threads available.

[image]

Does anyone has any encounter or anything to share how i may track this? Currently my thread dump capturing process is unable to capture this because often it is too late. Or is there any continuous thread dump capturing process i may consider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [define a JMX Notification via the Admin Console](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13714/config_diag_images.htm)

which will be picked up by [WebLogic Diagnostics Framework (WLDF)](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13714/config_notifications.htm#g1077172)

This creates a diagnostic snapshot which you can analyze later.

See how to create notification for watches

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E21764_01/apirefs.1111/e13952/taskhelp/diagnostics/CreateNotificationsForWatches.html

and specifically in admin console

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E21764_01/apirefs.1111/e13952/taskhelp/diagnostics/CreateWatchesForADiagnosticModule.html

> Select a watch type from the Watch Type list:
>
> •Select Collected Metrics to set a watch based on metrics collected
>   from MBean attributes. •Select Server Log to set a watch based on data
>   written to server logs. •Select Event Data to set a watch based on
>   data generated from a specified instrumentation event.